# jQuery Binding Woes

Tags: jquery, binding

I have a function:

```
function foo() { console.log('i run!'); }
```

And a binding to a button:

```
$(function() { 
   $('#myButton').click(foo);
});
```

I am *almost* positive that the console should not show 'i run!' until the button is clicked. I have no other `#myButton`s on the page (I have forple checked this), and yet `foo` continues to run when another unrelated button is clicked. There are no other references to foo (again, forple checked).

What could be happening here? Am I binding wrong?

Comment: something not revealed by your snippets is occurring...

Comment: Scott Evernden is so right that I not only voted up the comment but am posting to assert that he is in fact right.

Comment: I concur with the above comments. Here's my comment to reiterate how correct they are. :)

Answer (score 4):

You're not closing you're document ready block properly, it is missing a closing parenthesis (and optionally a semicolon), try:

```
$(function() { 
   $('#myButton').click(foo);
});
```

Comment: ehh... good catch, but i have it correct in my code... sorry... edited

Comment: Is there anything amiss in #myButton's markup (for instance, a missing '>'). Broken markup can cause weird behaviour. Maybe paste your #myButton code into the question. I honestly can't think of anything else!